# How to properly use DELETE by ID in Node.js/ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, fetch

I would like to explain my problem of the day.

i think it's harder than usual, so let me explain

here i start by getting a get

```
getRandom = async () => {
const res = await axios.get(
entrypoint + "/alluserpls"
)
this.setState({ data: res.data })
}
componentDidMount() {
this.getRandom()
}
```

here is my method for delete

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
const config = {
  method: "DELETE",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
};
const url = entrypoint + "/alluserpls";
fetch(url, config)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    if (res.error) {
      alert(res.error);
    } else {
      alert(`ajouté avec l'ID ${res}!`);
    }
  }).catch(e => {
    console.error(e);
  }).finally(() => this.setState({ redirect: true }));
```

}

then I map it

```
 render() {
 let datas = this.state.data.map((datass, index) => {
 return (
     <Col sm="12" key={index}>
     <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
         <button type="submit">Delete</button>
     </form>
        <div>{datass.name}</div>
     </Col>
```

then i return the result on my map

```
return (
  <div>  
    {datas}
   </div>
```

so works correctly , 
but the problem is the following when I want to delete only 1 CARD it deletes all my BDD

Here is my routes on BDD

```
   app.delete('/api/alluserpls', (req, res, ) => {
   const formData = req.body;
   connection.query('DELETE FROM alluserpls SET ?', formData, err => {
   if (err) {
   res.status(500).send("Erreur lors de la modification des users");
   } else {
   res.sendStatus(200);
   }
   });
   });
```

I would like that when I click on delete it only deletes the card and not all of my database.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, assign the `id` of the user to button `id` attribute field and then call the delete API with the user `id`

```
handleSubmit = (e, id) => {
e.preventDefault();
const userIdData = { id };
const config = {
  method: "DELETE",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(userIdData), 
};
const url = entrypoint + "/alluserpls";
fetch(url, config)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    if (res.error) {
      alert(res.error);
    } else {
      alert(`ajouté avec l'ID ${res}!`);
    }
  }).catch(e => {
    console.error(e);
  }).finally(() => this.setState({ redirect: true }));
```

, in the render method you can pass the `id` as variable to the `handleSubmit` function

```
render() {
 let datas = this.state.data.map((datass, index) => {
 return (
     <Col sm="12" key={index}>
     <form onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e, datass.id)}>
         <button type="submit">Delete</button>
     </form>
        <div>{datass.name}</div>
     </Col>
```

and in the backend you can get the id and delete only the particular user

```
app.delete('/api/alluserpls', (req, res, ) => {
   const formData = req.body;
   const userId = req.body.id;
   const deleteQuery = `DELETE from alluserpls WHERE id = ${userId}`;
   connection.query(deleteQuery, err => {
     if (err) {
       res.status(500).send("Erreur lors de la modification des users");
      } else {
       res.sendStatus(200);
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: console log the `err` in `connection.query` , there might be a problem with the DB query

Comment: code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'DELETE from alluserpls WHERE id = '
}
DELETE /api/alluserpls 500 15.629 ms - 40

Comment: have you added the `id` attribute to the button? like this `<button 
id={datass.id} type="submit">Delete</button>`

Comment: I have edited my answer can you check if that works!

Comment: I have a similar question, do you think I can ask it here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209716/discussion-between-hemanath-and-neff).